# object is treated as non-object

Tags: php, class, object

I've got another question.
I've got this **source_folder/class/controller/login.class.php** file:

```
<?php

/**
 * Controller that handles logging in
 *
 * @author Lysy
 */

class Controller_Login {

    private $oView;

    public function __construct($action) {
        $sAction = 'action_' . $action;
        $this->$sAction();
        $this->oView = new View_Login();
    }

    public function action_index() {
        echo 'Am I object ? '.(is_object($this->oView)) ? "Yes" : "No";
        $this->oView->showLoginAplet();
    }
}
?>
```

And this **source_folder/class/view/login.class.php** file:

```
<?php

/**
 * View that handles logging in
 *
 * @author Lysy
 */

class View_Login {

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function showLoginAplet() {
        echo '<form action="" method="POST">'
        . '<input type="text" name="login" value="login" />'
        . '<input type="text" name="pass" value="password" />'
        . '</form>';
    }
}
?>
```

When I try to load `Controller_Login('index')` in my **index.php** file (**__autoload** works perfectly), I get this result:

```
Yes
Fatal error: Call to a member function showLoginAplet() on a non-object in D:\Program Files\WebServ\httpd\class\controller\login.class.php on line 21
```

Why the *oView* variable is said to be an object (also why  "Am I object ? " is not displayed?) and then it is said to be non-object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your order is wrong, when you call `$this->$sAction();`, `$this->oView` is not instantiated yet, but you do use it in `action_index`. Fix like this:

```
public function __construct($action) {
        $this->oView = new View_Login();
        $sAction = 'action_' . $action;
        $this->$sAction();
}
```

About the subquestion, this:

```
echo 'Am I object ? '.(is_object($this->oView)) ? "Yes" : "No";
```

is evaluated as:

```
echo ('Am I object ? '.(is_object($this->oView))) ? "Yes" : "No";
```

which always renders to `"Yes"` as any non-empty string is considered `true`.

Comment: Oh I get it, thanks for help :) I'll be more carefull for such little bugs like this :)